# How to prevent cmd.exe and conhost processs from appearing when running .bat file from vbs script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I am using the below vbs script to run my file.bat batch script to prevent the command propmt window from appaearing but I noticed that the vbs script generates cmd.exe and conhost processes in task manager everytime i run it. any idea how i can prevent them from appearing?

```
 Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WshShell.Run "file.bat", 0
 Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Pretty sure that is impossible but I could be wrong.

Comment: This question is similar to: "How to open a spreadsheet without run excel.exe?" or "How to edit a text file without run notepad.exe?" Et cetera...

Comment: "I run .bat" means "I execute it via cmd.exe". You might create your own bat/cmd parser, or convert bat to vbs.

Comment: No, what you are trying to do is completely impossible......

Comment: To me, this question looks like "How do I run something and not let others see that it is running".

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute code, you have to run some type of process.  The types of commands you can execute in a batch file require a command processor because batch files aren't compiled into native code.  If you don't want separate console processes to run for those commands, you'll have to create the equivalent commands in vbs.  How difficult that would be depends on the length and complexity of your batch file.